Picturebox does not display Bitmap image - remains white
From an IDS camera I do get an image which is shown in a picturebox (_display_Zoom0) which is working. Now I do have another picturebox (image_zoom1) where the same image shall be shown but cropped. Therefore I use this code:

Bitmap bitmap;
_camera.Memory.ToBitmap(s32MemID, out bitmap);

if (bitmap != null)
{
    Rectangle CropArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 400);
    Bitmap croppedBitmap = bitmap.Clone(CropArea, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    image_zoom1.Image = croppedBitmap;

    _camera.Display.Render(s32MemID, m_RenderMode);
    _camera.Memory.Unlock(s32MemID);
    
    _camera.Display.Render(s32MemID, _display_Zoom0, uEye.Defines.DisplayRenderMode.FitToWindow);
}

"out bitmap" is the image from the camera which will be cropped and shown in image_zoom1.
Problem:
The picturebox image_zoom1 does not shown anything and is white. In order to check if the cropped bitmap has a content I used this code:
croppedBitmap.Save("croppedImage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

The saved cropped image shows the correct, cropped image (not white).
Has someone an idea why I can not display the cropped image "directly" in the picturebox?
Thanks

What ViewMode does the PB have?  What size is the uncropped image?

ViewMode is Zoom but others are also not working. The size is half of the original image

Hm, strange. Can you post an example of the  uncropped image in its original format?

well the size of the uncropped image is 1200x800 in Format32bppArgb Format. Does it has an impact?

No, this shouldn't be a problem. Can you just try some other image from a different source to see if that makes a difference?
